# PDG: Understanding the $Z^{0}$ decay modes

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model

I would like to understand the hadronic decays of the $Z^{0}$ vector boson better, as they are listed [in PDG on page 3](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2020/listings/rpp2020-list-z-boson.pdf): [image]

(i) What kind of particle(s) is/are $$\frac{\bar{u}u + c\bar{c}}{2} \quad ?$$

(ii) Could the $Z^{0}$ also directly decay into **one** $\pi^{0}$ meson?

Comment: If you look at $Γ_{22}$  in your linke (ii) is answered in the affirmative.. Think of jets and then the other  $Γ$s below   have the answer for (1)

Comment: Concerning (ii): I was thinking more of $Z^{0}\rightarrow \pi^{0}$, I edited my question.

Comment: At the center of mass, which is geometrically the same before and after the decay, energy conservation would be violated, because the only energy at the center of mass is the mass of the particle.

Comment: Makes sense, good point!

Comment: 2. If the *Z* were highly virtual and it had $E^2-p^2= (0.135 GeV)^2$ instead of $(91 GeV)^2$ of the real *Z*, yes. As long as you know you are 6 orders of magnitude away in *s*...

Comment: Okay, this also makes sense. :)

Comment: If you go to PDG live and click the link for Γ9, it answers your question https://pdglive.lbl.gov/BranchingRatio.action?desig=21&parCode=S044&home=